# What does EOF FOUND '}' mean in Check style?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, eof, checkstyle, intellij-14

I'm using intellij communicated version and also add checkstyle plugin

how ever, i made simple java file just say hello

```
public class hello {
public static void main(string[] final args)
{
    system.out.println("hello, world");

}
}
```

it's simply run. however checkstyle tell me there is problem at the last line.
he told me

> Got an exception-expecting EOF, Found '}' error

I don't know what is the problem. block is correctly close.
is there something i need to add or fix that ?

Comment: Try adding empty line at the end of the file

Comment: (Above it should be `final String[]` and `System` with capital.) That error should mean there is an extra `{`. Do an automatic reformat in your IDE. Also placing the cursor at a brace, will often show the scope of the braces, or highlight the other brace. Or allow you to jump back and forth.

Comment: Seems you didn't posted the exact code that checkstyle warns. It could be a better identification if you post exact code.

Comment: i changed String and System to capital, thx and exact error message is that "Got an exception -expeting EOF,Found'}](8:5)"

Comment: You've already tried what @StavSaad suggests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try formatting it like

```
public class Hello 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     System.out.println("hello, world");
  }
}
```

and the "s" in system.out.println and string[], should be capital

Checkstyle is a tool which is used to find flaws in formatting and coding conventions followed if any exists in the code. The rules are set using by configuring the checkstyle. And if any part of your code does not abide by them, it will throw an exception. In most of the cases exceptions will be self explanatory. You can use google depending on the exception you get.

Comment: Format is the problem??

Comment: Checkstyle is used to find the formatting errors. The exceptions which are thrown are a way to tell us where our formatting is not correct as per the rule. The rules depend on how our checkstyle is configured.

Comment: Also please make the "s" in system.out.println capital

Comment: Still you dind't modify system to System. As its dealing with code standards, you should also make your class name starts with capital letter (Hello).

Comment: i copy your code and paste it. but the message still exist.. maybe i need to reinstll my IDE...

Comment: It depends on how you have configured the checkstyle rules in your IDE. Check if [this](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/#!/custom-config) link is helps. This is for eclipse

Answer (score 2):

This problem became a real issue in the `checkstyle` project. Basically it was related with the use of lambdas, yet the problem exposed herebefore is clarely not related to Java 8 lambdas. You can check the issue [here](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/10). You can solve it by specifying a valid version. In gradle it would be:

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
checkstyle {
    toolVersion = "6.1.1"
}
```